# Statistics about development of average connection speed and latency over the years

Tags: performance, page-speed

Are there any statistics about the development of average internet connection speed and request latency from households to major sites over the years?

I find this information very useful for ajax related software design (i.e. feasibility studies of several webapp use cases).

Comment: Are you interested in households in a specific country, or worldwide?

Comment: I am especially interested in European countries and the US.

Answer (score 1):

I found good statistics at http://www.netindex.com/ but only ranging back to 2008 and with no explicit latency rate measurements.